# Photo gallery with fetch API in React.js needs iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch, setstate

In my project made in React.js I'm having a problem with **ITERATIONS**. In this React Component (ViewSectionList) I am **fetching** 6 images. And each of them IS from a different API.

My code allows to render these pictures, but it is not efficient, mainly because I don't know how to:

1. get all the images from multiple API urls in one single fetch (I
   tried **Promise.all**, but then I couldn't recognize get data as JSON (resp.json not working )
2. how to save found images in a single array (in **fetch's setstate**)
3. how to use map function to render obtained data

The images are hidden in API as response[0].urls.small For simplicity, I shortened fetch's and div's in render up to one

I would be grateful for any help :)

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import { Router, Route, Link, IndexLink, IndexRoute, hashHistory} from 
 'react-router';

class ViewSectionList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
        imgs: [] // I'm not using it :(
    };
}

componentDidMount() {

    let urls = [
        'https://api.site.com/categories/2/photos/?client_id=MY-API', 
        'https://api.site.com/categories/3/photos/?client_id=MY-API', 
        'https://api.site.com/categories/4/photos/?client_id=MY-API', 
        'https://api.site.com/categories/8/photos/?client_id=MY-API', 
        'https://api.site.com/categories/6/photos/?client_id=MY-API', 
        'https://api.site.com/categories/7/photos/?client_id=MY-API', 
    ]

    // ------ HOW TO ITERATE THIS FETCH? ------
    fetch(urls[0])
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(response => {
        // -------- HOW TO SAVE DATA INTO A SINGLE ARRAY?
        this.setState({  img2: response[0].urls.small  })
    })

}
render() {

    return (
        <div className="gallery">
             <h1>Section list</h1>
             <div className="section-list">

                // ------HOW TO MAP THESE ELEMENTS
                <Link className="single-section" to="/section/2">
                    <img className="image" src={this.state.img2} alt="" />
                </Link>
             </div>
         </div>
    )
}
}
export { ViewSectionList }
```

Comment: one after the other (Array#reduce can help), or all at once (Promise.all will be what you want)? If as you say, using `Promise.all` confused you regarding it's results, perhaps you're doing it wrong

Comment: Seems you may want `Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url).then(r => r.json()).then(r => r[0].urls.small))).then(imgs => this.setState({imgs}));`

Comment: @JaromandaX, your code works! Thank you very much!